# Prevent the App from using RippleDrawable

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have a Button in a DialogFragment that the background is a custom drawable (shape) and I use getBackground to update its color and stroke

```
(GradientDrawable) gradientDrawable = button.getBackground().mutate();
gradientDrawable.setColor(some_color);
gradientDrawable.setStroke(some_color);
```

The problem is that when the App has Material design dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'
```

the cast fails because the drawable is RippleDrawable.

How can I prevent the App from using RippleDrawable in this Fragment?